# Convert Apache Rewrite Mod Rewrite to Nginx

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx

I want to use Hostbill with Nginx but still retain the SEO URLs as well. Can someone help me out here? Thanks

This would be the .htaccess hostbill tells me to create

```
## create .htaccess file in main HostBill directory with contents below
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /billing/
RewriteRule ^downloads/?$ ?cmd=downloads [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I want to be able to convert it to Nginx, I've already tried the converters online, they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what rewrite base would mean, but if it means that the rewrite only happens in that directory then

```
location /billing {
  rewrite "(?i)^downloads/?$" /?cmd=downloads last;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /billing/index.php?$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. The RewriteBase is the base for hostbill, so the downloads folder and index.php is in there.

Comment: O I see, so the `try_files` should go inside the location too, gonna edit my answer

Comment: It's doesn't worth though.